# Can't update a value in a Dictionary inside an Array?

Tags: swift

I recently moved from Objective-C to Swift, and I'm having an issue with the following example:

```
var test: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["value": true]]

var aaa: [String: AnyObject] = test[0]
print(aaa["value"])  // prints Optional(1)
aaa["value"] = false
print(aaa["value"])  // prints Optional(0)

var bbb: [String: AnyObject] = test[0]
print(bbb["value"])  // prints Optional(1) again???
```

How come the change is not stored in the `test` array?

Thank you.

Comment: @Dhivya Both references are not related to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift `Dictionary` is value type not reference type so you need to set it that dictionary with array after making changes.

```
var test: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["value": true]]

var aaa: [String: AnyObject] = test[0]
print(aaa["value"])  // prints Optional(1)
aaa["value"] = false
print(aaa["value"])  // prints Optional(0)

//Replace old dictionary with new one
test[0] = aaa    

var bbb: [String: AnyObject] = test[0]
print(bbb["value"])  // prints Optional(0)
```

**Or** You can try simply this way:

```
test[0]["value"] = false
```

Comment: But is this only with Dictionary?
Should I expect this with Array as well? `[[true], [true]]` ?

Comment: Array of boolean is also value type, so that also not possible, But you can simply set `array[0][1] = false` No need to first extract value and set it and then replace object in array.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much.

Comment: @thedp Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

directly change from main array

```
test[0]["value"] = false
```